# Reverse vertex order in THREE.js face

Tags: javascript, three.js

I need to reverse vertex order in faces of my geometry.
In example:

```
// create geometry
var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
// create vertices
geometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3( 0,   0,   0 ) );
geometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3( 0,   100, 0 ) );
geometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3( 100, 0,   0 ) );
// create face
var face = new THREE.Face3( 0, 1, 2 );
geometry.faces.push ( face );
// compute normals
geometry.computeFaceNormals();
geometry.computeVertexNormals();
// add to scene
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(
    geometry,
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x00ffff})
);
scene.add( mesh );
```

Now I need to change order of vertices in face from 0,1,2 to 2,1,0. But when I do this manually it does not work no matter which flags for update I set to true.

The question - is it possible to reverse vertices order on the fly and if yes then how?

**Important** - It's better to avoid using negative scale for geometry in this case. And it's also better to avoid re-creating of object.

THREE.js: r73

Comment: What you need to manipulate is indices, not vertices. Look at `geometry.attributes.index.array` for order of triangles composition.

Comment: `attributes` is a part of `BufferGeometry` but I use usual geometry. There's no indices in there I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
delete mesh.geometry.__directGeometry;
```

This should apply yours changes. In some reason in r72 and r73 __directGeometry not updated automatically.